# Copy 1D array to 2D array

Tags: java

Using C/C++ it is possible to do the following:

```
int arr[100];
int ar[10][10];
memcpy(ar, arr, sizeof(int)*100);
```

Because the C/C++ standard guarantees that arrays are contiguous, the above will copy 1D array to 2D array.

Is this possible in Java ?

Comment: No, you have to loop. If anything, java guarantees the 100 is contiguous but the 10x10 isn't. Java's int[][] is really c's int**, not an int[][].

Comment: Have you tried java.lang.System.arraycopy? http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/system_arraycopy.htm

Comment: For Java 7, instead of `System.arraycopy`, you can use `java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(...)`. This doesn't create multi-dimensional arrays, but it can be used within the loop.

Comment: Can check and see how `java.lang.reflect.Array` creates Dimensional Arrays. Then somehow index each dimension.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in Java because a multidimensional array in Java is actually an array of arrays. The elements are not stored in a contiguous block of memory. You will need to copy the elements row by row.

For example, here's one of several possible techniques:

```
int arr[100] = . . .;
int ar[10][10] = new int[10][10];
int offset = 0;
for (int[] row : ar) {
    System.arraycopy(arr, offset, row, 0, row.length);
    offset += row.length;
}
```

From the [Java Language Specification, §15.10.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.1), here are the steps that happen when evaluating the array creation expression `new int[10][10]` (note in particular the last point):

> - First, the dimension expressions are evaluated, left-to-right. If any of the expression evaluations completes abruptly, the expressions to the right of it are not evaluated.
> - Next, the values of the dimension expressions are checked. If the value of any DimExpr expression is less than zero, then a NegativeArraySizeException is thrown.
> - Next, space is allocated for the new array. If there is insufficient space to allocate the array, evaluation of the array creation expression completes abruptly by throwing an OutOfMemoryError.
> - Then, if a single DimExpr appears, a one-dimensional array is created of the specified length, and each component of the array is initialized to its default value (§4.12.5).
> - Otherwise, if n DimExpr expressions appear, then array creation effectively executes a set of nested loops of depth n-1 to create the implied arrays of arrays.