# Ignoring CSV values with openCSV + Storing int values from CSV file in separate two-dimensional array elements

Tags: java, arrays, opencsv

First part to my question is, if I have a CSV file with 4 numbers on one line separated by a comma, how do I ignore the first two values using openCSV?

Now, consider the following array:

```
int[][] parsedData = new int [10][10];
```

and the following line from a CSV file:

```
54, 68, 5, 1
```

assuming the former is possible (ignoring the first two values on a line in a CSV file), how do I then parse the value '5' into parsedData[0][0] and parse the value '1' into parsedData[0][1]?

I can't find anything in the openCSV documentation that would explain how to do this, nor can I wrap my head around even doing it if there weren't a CSV file to read beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that within opencsv.  You can ignore entire lines with the skiplines (which is normally used when the data has an header) but not part of a line.  You will have to do that yourself programmatically.

Take a look at the java [System.arraycopy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)) method.  I found an article on stack overflow with [a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22673406/copy-1d-array-to-2d-array).

Hope that helps.

:)